# libgdx Viewports - Why when I use FitViewport the touch input x and y is not accurate?

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d, viewport

libgdx Viewports - Why when I use FitViewport the touch input x and y is not accurate?
[image]

Comment: How are you obtaining X and Y?

Comment: I obtain it using InputAdapter touchDown to get screenX and screenY, then pass to Vector3 touchpoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0) and camera.unproject(touchpoint) to get the world coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `viewport.unproject()` instead of `camera.unproject()` so the cropping of the FitViewport is taken into acount.